# is it possible to not mangling in .NET minification?

Tags: javascript, .net, bundling-and-minification

To bundle and minify the files of my application I'm using **.NET Bundling and Minification** feature (and it's complicated to use any other tool, so I would like to find a solution for this).

As a remark and just in case it could help, I'm trying to minify `angular` files, files compiled from `typescript` and regular `javascript` files.

The problem is that when I execute the application I got some javascript  exceptions related mostly to `angular`. I think it's not useful but maybe it could help, so this is the main exception I get:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- highChartSeriesMappingService
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t%20%3C-%20highChartSeriesMappingService
>   [Rest of the exception trace][...]

If I just bundle them and no minify my files, by setting this instruction `myScriptBundle.Transforms.Clear()`, it works fine. Obviously, this action also avoids the mangling of variables, classes...names.

In order to be sure of what was happening, I used [`grunt`](http://gruntjs.com/) and its plugin [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify) to bundle and minify. At the beginning I had the same problem as before because of the basic configuration I used for the task:

```
      uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false
            },
            myScript: {
                files: {
                    'myScript.min.js': conf.myScript
                }
            }
        }
```

Where `conf` is a reference to a `json` file with the url of the files to minify. But when I set the `mangle` property to false ([here you have more info about it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify#mangle)):

```
      uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false,
                mangle: false
            },
            myScript: {
                files: {
                    'myScript.min.js': conf.myScript
                }
            }
        }
```

It works fine too. It leads me to think that is the mangling of some classes names the root of the problem.

As you can see, I reached a solution using `grunt` but I would like to find a way to avoid mangling with `.NET`. Any idea?

Comment: I think your problem with minifing  AngularJs, there are some practice to avoid conflict with angular you have to follow to safe minfication  https://www.sitepoint.com/5-minutes-to-min-safe-angular-code-with-grunt/

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed I've read the link you posted in your comment and although I write all the angular code using the array syntax, in the project I work which is shared with other developers, there were some classes where the dependencies injection wasn't done with the strings array. So after check some classes and fix them, now the minification through .NET is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read the post of @AbdelrhmanMohamed and check again my project's files I realized that it was a problem related to `angular` and its array sytntax; some files lacked the dependencies injection through the array strings, so when those files where minimizied and the functions' names where mangled caused my exception in execution time.

To sum up, .NET bndling and minification process seems to work fine. If you work with angular you just have to be sure that all your classes which depend of other modules have the array string with those dependencies defined.